# Regexp: replace questionmark with quote (due to import errors)

Tags: regex

I need to replace a question-mark `?` with a single quote `'`. However, only when the "?" is between two letters: `qu?est-ce que c?est` should become `qu'est-ce que c'est`.

`How are you?` should remain unchanged.

Additionally, quoted text like `this is ?very? nice` should become `this is 'very' nice`

Hope there is a RegExp expert out there who can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match this regex:

```
([a-zA-Z])\?([a-zA-Z])
```

and replace with:

```
$1'$2
```

Answer (score 0):

And Matching

```
\?([a-zA-Z]+)\?
```

and replacing with

```
'$1'
```

solves the additional question.